# postgres function to load yearly data

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 functions:
1st is for month data which takes in date parameter (last date of any month), this is truncate and load.
2nd is for yearly data which uses above function to append data in yearly table. The parameter is number of months (ex. if parameter is 12, it should give last 12 months, if its 6, it should give last 6 months)
For our example its 12.

function 1 is called as below:

```
select * from fn_monthly('2021-08-31')
```

For 2nd fucntion, we basically need to iterate based on months parameter and execute the function.
Its defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_yearly(in months int)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
                v_months int = (months*-1)+2;
                v_date date;
    
                
    begin -- executes all code including exception logic
            begin -- returns success if no exception
        
            
            
            
            truncate table yearly_table;
        
        
            for counter in reverse 1..v_months loop
                v_date := (Date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '% month - 1 day',counter)::date;
-- this should put last date of month in variable v_date
-- example when counter is 1, then v_date = '2021-08-31' 
-- example when counter is 0, then v_date = '2021-07-31' 
-- example when counter is -1, then v_date = '2021-06-30' 
--this is the date I needs to pass into the monthly function

                
                
                select * from fn_monthly(v_date);

                insert into yearly_table(col1,col2) select col1,col2 from monthly_table;
                
            
            end loop;
            
        end; -- returns success if no exception
        $function$
;
```

when I execute the above function, I get below error:

```
ErrorCode:42846, ErrorMsg:cannot cast type record to date
```

Whats the best way to solve this issue? Maybe some other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error concerns this expression:

```
(Date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '% month - 1 day',counter)::date
```

You wanted to format an interval with `'% month - 1 day',counter` but the syntax is not acceptable in this context, use:

```
(Date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month'* counter - interval '1 day')::date
```